# Unable to design date range picker in NextJs Project

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am stuck with a design issue. I am unable to implement a date range picker as per the client's requirement. I am working on a website where I have to develop the design as per the mockup. I tried to implement Airbnb react dates. But the customization curve is too high for me, especially for the dates input field. Although I have developed the base layout when I try to implement any date range picker it is breaking the design. It would be a great help if someone could help me to implement the date range picker as per the mockup design. I am sharing my code along with the GitHub repo link where I have shared the codes and also a demo of the working design.

I have organized the components in a component directory that contains two-component one is Header and another one is a header widget. In the header widget component, I have tried to implement a date picket design. I am sharing the code of the header and header widget section for detailed understanding.

GitHub Link - https://github.com/ramanujamgond/header-widget.git

Demo Link - https://header-widget.vercel.app/

**Mockup Design**

[Mockup of the design - The date range picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD1cK.jpg)

Note - I have only added the bare design, without any functionality and API call. Just an HTML boilerplate or skeleton.

**Header Component**

```
import Image from 'next/image';

// import logo
import Logo from '../../assets/images/logo.png';

// import masthead image
import mastHead from '../../assets/images/masthead.png';

// import property overview icon details
import PropertryDetails from '../../assets/images/53-plus-hotels.svg';
import Location100Plus from '../../assets/images/100-locations.svg';
import BestPriceGurantee from '../../assets/images/best-guarantee.svg';
import Travelers74Mn from '../../assets/images/74mn-travelers.svg';
import TopHeader from './TopHeader';

// import widget
import HeaderWidget from '../widget/HeaderWidget';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <section className="position-relative">
                <div className="header-glass-wrapper">
                    <TopHeader />
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-transparent margin-top">
                        <div className="container">
                            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                <Image src={Logo} alt="Picture of the author" height="65" />
                            </a>
                            <button className="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseNavbar">
                                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div className="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapseNavbar">
                                <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                                    <li className="nav-item">
                                        <a className="nav-link nav-text-color mx-4" href="">Menu 1</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li className="nav-item">
                                        <a className="nav-link nav-text-color mx-4" href="">Menu 2</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li className="nav-item">
                                        <a className="nav-link nav-text-color mx-4" href="">Menu 3</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li className="nav-item">
                                        <a className="nav-link nav-text-color mx-4" href="">Menu 4</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li className="nav-item">
                                        <a className="nav-link nav-text-color mx-4" href="">Menu 5</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <header>
                    <Image src={mastHead} className="masthead" alt="Hero Image" />
                    <div className="widget-select-wrapper">
                        <div className="widget-heading-wrapper">
                            <div className="standard-cursive-text">Explore the</div>
                            <div className="widget-heading">Unexplored</div>
                        </div>

                        <HeaderWidget />
                    </div>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div className="website-overview">
                                    <Image src={PropertryDetails} alt="Property detail icon" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div className="website-overview">
                                    <Image src={Location100Plus} alt="Property detail icon" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div className="website-overview">
                                    <Image src={BestPriceGurantee} alt="Property detail icon" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div className="website-overview">
                                    <Image src={Travelers74Mn} alt="Property detail icon" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>

                <div className="cloud-pattern"></div>
            </section>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

**Header Widget**

```
import React from 'react';

// import react tabs
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel, resetIdCounter } from 'react-tabs';
import 'react-tabs/style/react-tabs.css';

const HeaderWidget = () => {
    resetIdCounter();
    return (
        <>
            <div className="multiple-widget-item-wrapper">
                <Tabs>
                    <TabList>
                        <Tab>Hotels</Tab>
                        <Tab>Holiday Packages</Tab>
                        <Tab>Boat Houses</Tab>
                        <Tab>Sightseeing</Tab>
                    </TabList>

                    <TabPanel>
                        <div className="widget-date-range-picker">
                            <div className="location-search-wrapper"><input className="form-control location-search" type="text" placeholder="Enter Location" /></div>
                            <div className="date-picker-wrapper-checkIn"><input className="form-control date-picker-check-in" type="text" placeholder="22 Sept 2021" /></div>
                            <div className="date-picker-wrapper-checkOut"><input className="form-control date-picker-check-out" type="text" placeholder="23 Sept 2021" /></div>
                            <div><button type="button" className="btn standard-search-btn">Search</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </TabPanel>

                    <TabPanel>
                        <div className="widget-date-range-picker">
                            <div className="location-search-wrapper"><input className="form-control location-search" type="text" placeholder="Enter Location" /></div>
                            <div className="date-picker-wrapper-checkIn"><input className="form-control date-picker-check-in" type="text" placeholder="22 Sept 2021" /></div>
                            <div className="date-picker-wrapper-checkOut"><input className="form-control date-picker-check-out" type="text" placeholder="23 Sept 2021" /></div>
                            <div><button type="button" className="btn standard-search-btn">Search</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </TabPanel>

                    <TabPanel>
                        <div className="widget-date-range-picker">
                            <div className="location-search-wrapper"><input className="form-control location-search" type="text" placeholder="Enter Location" /></div>
                            <div className="date-picker-wrapper-checkIn"><input className="form-control date-picker-check-in" type="text" placeholder="22 Sept 2021" /></div>
                            <div className="date-picker-wrapper-checkOut"><input className="form-control date-picker-check-out" type="text" placeholder="23 Sept 2021" /></div>
                            <div><button type="button" className="btn standard-search-btn">Search</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </TabPanel>

                    <TabPanel>
                        <div className="widget-date-range-picker">
                            <div className="location-search-wrapper"><input className="form-control location-search" type="text" placeholder="Enter Location" /></div>
                            <div className="date-picker-wrapper-checkIn"><input className="form-control date-picker-check-in" type="text" placeholder="22 Sept 2021" /></div>
                            <div className="date-picker-wrapper-checkOut"><input className="form-control date-picker-check-out" type="text" placeholder="23 Sept 2021" /></div>
                            <div><button type="button" className="btn standard-search-btn">Search</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </TabPanel>
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default HeaderWidget;
```

Comment: Where is this mockup to which you're referring?

Comment: Just click on the link - Mockup of the design - The date range picker. I can not add the image inline as StackOverflow is not allowing me to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use material-ui date picker component in your app. [Date Picker](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Smart Developer - Yes definitely will try to implement the date picker. Is it compatible with nextjs? Let me go through the documents.

Comment: @string1301 Yes I believe it is. Here is an example of a website made with React,Material-Ui and next js. https://bazar-react.vercel.app/